# Is Homebrew's 'install' warning an error?

Tags: macos, terminal, shell, script, homebrew

When using the `brew install foo` command with `foo` already installed returns

```
Warning: foo-3.5.2 already installed
```

Is this technically an error, like stderr, or is this message simply stdout? It is not specified in the documentation. I ask because I have a script that goes:

```
#!/bin/bash
brew install foo
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo OK
else
    echo FAIL
fi
```

(It's a simple script to help me learn if-then conditionals--don't judge!) Each time I run it, the script returns `OK` in conjunction with the above `Warning`. This would suggest that the warning is not an error/failure, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a warning being printed by the brew application, but bash is not aware of an error. Whether bash sees it as an error depends on whether the application sends it to the error stream or the output stream, and what the exit code is. Since you are getting OK returned from your script, bash thinks the command is returning 0, which means the bash command ran successfully. So, brew must send warnings of this type to stdout, rather than stderr.

Are you aware of how to use 2> to redirect stderr to a file? 
You could redirect stderr (2) and stdout while running your script, to two different files. Then you could see to which stream the warning is printed.

```
./script.sh > stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt
```

Comment: most excellent, thanks! brew's warning is, in fact, an error that homebrew re-directs to stdout? Essentially, homebrew is tricking bash into thinking everything is hunky-dory, and this is because all bash cares about is whether the command was successfully passed, correct? Bash cares nothing about truthvalue, only logical validity?

Comment: It depends how the application was written - the writers of brew could have chosen to make it exit with a non-zero code to bash, to make bash know there was an error. Apparently, they have it exit 0 (success code), and then print the brew error. 

If you write a bash script, you can insert exit directives at different points, and set exit codes (any number you want, really). Then, you should document which code means what error. For example, tar exits with 0 if it is perfectly successful, 1 if some files differ, or 2 for a fatal error. Exit codes can also be called a return value or a status.